# IEnumerable.Except() on System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator vs. List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, except

Maybe I am missing the details here but I would expect that IEnumerable.Except() would work on Enumerables not concretely cast to a collection.

Let me explain with a simple example: I have a list of files on a directory and I want to exclude the files that start with a certain string.

```
var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\").Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
```

Getting both the files matching and those not matching would be a matter of identifying one of the two collections and then .Except()-ing on the full list, right?

```
var matching = allfiles.Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("TOKEN"));
```

and

```
var notmatching = allfiles.Except(matching, new FileComparer());
```

Where FileComparer() is some class that compares the full path of the two files.

Well, **unless I cast both of the three collections to a List, the last notmatching variable still gives me the full list of files after I .Except() on the matching collection**. To be clear:

```
var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\").Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
var matching = allfiles.Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("TOKEN"));
var notmatching = allfiles.Except(matching, new FileComparer());
```

does not exclude, while

```
var allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\").Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToList();
var matching = allfiles.Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("TOKEN")).ToList();
var notmatching = allfiles.Except(matching, new FileComparer()).ToList();
```

actually does what is says on the tin. 
What am I missing here? I can't understand why LINQ doesn't manipulate the collection not currently cast to a list.

For instance, the FileComparer does not even get called in the first case.

```
internal class FileComparer : IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>
{
    public bool Equals(FileInfo x, FileInfo y)
    {
        return x == null ? y == null : (x.Name.Equals(y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.Length == y.Length);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: FileComparer does not even get called in the first version, without the .ToList().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two is that without `ToList`, the deferred `allfiles` query is executed twice, producing different instances of `FileInfo` that will not pass reference equality.

Your `FileComparer` [implements `GetHashCode` incorrectly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1.gethashcode), as it simply returns the reference-based hash code of the `FileInfo` objects (which does not itself override `GetHashCode`).

> Implementations are required to ensure that if the `Equals(T, T)` method returns `true` for two objects `x` and `y`, then the value returned by the `GetHashCode(T)` method for `x` must equal the value returned for `y`.

The solution is to implement `GetHashCode` based on the same definition of equality as `Equals`:

```
public int GetHashCode(FileInfo obj)
{
    return StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(obj.Name);
}
```

Comment: The difference between the two is that without ToList, the deferred allfiles query is executed twice, producing different instances of FileInfo that will not pass reference equality. 

Aaah I should have thought about that. Many thanks for the explanation and for the fix, it makes sense now.